# C++: How to read a native video file (.xrf) using Kinect1 SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I have a video in raw format (.xrf) with depth data saved using Kinect SDK. Now I want to read that file, so I can do skeletal analysis. I tried to search on the internet but most of the resources talk about reading from the Kinect sensor directly.

It would be great if you can please help me by providing information about any useful resource or code snippet to get me started. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kinect v2, read out data from .xef files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280689/kinect-v2-read-out-data-from-xef-files)

Comment: I am looking to read .xrf or raw files and not .xef files.